Google cloud build and nodejs mysql connect
I'm having hard time to figure how to configure a database connection on cloudbuild.yaml file.
cloudbuild.yaml:
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    automapSubstitutions: true
    env:
      - 'DB_USER=aaa'
      - 'DB_PASS=aaa'
      - 'DB_NAME=dbaaaa'
      - 'DB_HOST=101.152.223.144'

options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY

I cannot use env variables in cloud run ...
Why cannot connect on build time to database without exposing the connection data...?
Thanks in advance
I've try env variables with cloud run .
Env variables of cloud run dont work at build time (Cloud build).
Use env variables on cloudbuild.yaml file.
